# Is it really necessary to use array, to display an innerHTML of a complete node list after child remove?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, innerhtml, removechild

This code works well but when I start to remove nodes the complete list disappear and I'm left with one node in the innerHTML, instead of removing one by one gradually which is what I want. To leave a few to none behind perhaps gradually instead of straight one for all displayed in the innerHTML, of the div that displays the removal sort of say... I can perfectly do this to work using arrays but I'm curious if there's an way out without using any(arrays)?

HTML code

```
<button onClick="remov()">remove</button>
<button onClick="addDiv()">Add Div</button>
<div>
<div></div>
<div></div><div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
<div id="tt"></div>
```

Javascript Code

```
var stage = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
var tt = document.getElementById("tt");

function remov() {
    if (stage.hasChildNodes()) {
        stage.removeChild(stage.firstChild);
        for (var i = 0; i < stage.childNodes.length; i++) {
            tt.innerHTML = stage.childNodes[i].nodeName;
        }

        if (!stage.hasChildNodes()) {
            tt.innerHTML = "no nodes";
        }
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < stage.childNodes.length; i++) {
    tt.innerHTML += stage.childNodes[i].nodeName;
}

function addDiv() {
    var a = document.createElement("div");
    stage.appendChild(a);
    if (!stage.hasChildNodes()) {
        tt.innerHTML += stage.firstChild.nodeName;
    } else {
        tt.innerHTML += stage.lastChild.nodeName
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jobson111/UzN7L/2/)

Comment: "<div></div<div></div>" is malformed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display all divs during their removal need to change = to += as below

```
function remov() {
    tt.innerHTML=''; //EDIT forgot to add in this line
    if (stage.hasChildNodes()) {
        stage.removeChild(stage.firstChild);
        for (var i = 0; i < stage.childNodes.length; i++) {
            tt.innerHTML += stage.childNodes[i].nodeName;  //<------- + needed to display all divs
        }

        if (!stage.hasChildNodes()) {
            tt.innerHTML = "no nodes";
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UzN7L/5/) added

Comment: I tried that a million times a million, and still did not get the result I intended which is to remove one by one gradually.

Comment: Not sure what result you intend. Have made changes I suggested in fiddle now added and it seems to remove each child one at a time on the click of the remove button.

Comment: Yes jing that's the proper result, now if it isn't asking to much can you give me a hint what innerHTML='' means?

Comment: If there is HTML such as <div id='holder'><span>contents</span>more stuff<br>even more<p>new bits</p></div> then innerHTML is method of accessing the HTML that is inside a particular tag as a string, either reading it or setting it. So D=document.getElementByID('holder') then D.innerHTML='<span>contents</span>more stuff<br>even more<p>new bits</p>'

Comment: Thank you for the help and, for remembering me of the innerHTML method. Let's see if I got right this time, the innerHTML='blank' is a string of the div for say in this case, and it erases the child nodes of a of a parent node. Did I get it right this time? Like you mentioned either reading it or setting it, is that so? In my case it give place to a new child node because of the extra coding, is this right?

Comment: Yes though strictly speaking innerHTML='blank' would set the content of the parent node to be the word blank.     innerHTML='' erases the child nodes of a parent